# Skinning Control Backgrounds - Better Performance?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

sorry if this question is overly simple, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create backgrounds to controls - in the hopes that it will improve app performance.

I have 9 different controls. All of them have a background. The backgrounds are made up of either images, other controls or both. All of those backgrounds have another background.

Think of this like Power Point with slides, slide layouts and slide masters - inherited in that order. I have 9 slides / controls.

- The first 3 controls have the same "control layout" (let's call it
  **ControlLayout1**). **ControlLayout1** gets some of it's elements from **ControlMaster1**.
- The second 3 controls also have the same control layout, but it is
  different from the first. Let's call it **ControlLayout2**. It also
  inherits from **ControlMaster1**.
- The final set of 3 controls are different again. We can call them
  **ControlLayout3**. But this time, they inherit from a different master - **ControlMaster2**.

Right now in each control I'm writing out all the XAML each time separately. I'm thinking there must be a way to not write these in each of these each item. Ideally, what I would like to create is one set of XAML that can be reused.

Here's some pseudo-XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Name="Control1">
    <MyBackground (ControlLayout1)/>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Name="Control2">
    <MyBackground (ControlLayout2)/>
</UserControl>

<UserControl x:Name="Control3">
    <MyBackground (ControlLayout3)/>
</UserControl>
```

And then somewhere for **ControlLayouts** (I don't know, like Application.Resources or elsewhere)

```
<Canvas x:Name="ControlLayout1">
    <MyMasterBackground (ControlMaster1)/>
</Canvas>

<Canvas x:Name="ControlLayout2">
    <MyMasterBackground (ControlMaster1)/>
    <TextBox Text="The Control 2">
</Canvas>

<Canvas x:Name="ControlLayout3">
    <MyMasterBackground (ControlMaster2)/>
    <TextBox Text="The Control 3">
</Canvas>
```

And then for the **ControlMasters**

```
<Canvas x:Name="ControlMaster1">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/image1.jpg" />
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>

<Canvas x:Name="ControlMaster2">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/image2.jpg" />
    </Canvas.Background>
    <TextBox Text="Control Master 1">
</Canvas>
```

Once defined, the ControlLayouts and ControlMasters never need to change - they are static.

Beyond just having a smaller XAP if I can put these all in one location and reuse the XAML, I'm hoping performance will be improved in my app as the ControlLayouts automatically get BitmapCached or something like that.

So first, is there a good strategy to implement the above (the ControlLayouts and Masters do not have any code-behind)? Secondly will performance be improved in loading of Control1, Control2, etc.? Finally, if they were pure usercontrols (i.e. they had some code behind), would that be better for performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want static things to be BitmapCached, you should just set it manually. Certain things are [auto-cached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602285(v=vs.95).aspx), but in my experience setting it manually can make a BIG difference, particularly when you are moving UI elements around a lot and seeing jerky performance.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is a combination of a few things:

About the Background thing: just create a dependency property (let's call it MyBackgroundDP) of type Brush in the code behind of a UserControl, and bind it to your XAML like:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid Background={"Binding MyBackgroundDP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestoryType=UserControl}}">
     <!-- More XAML declarations -->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

To create the dependency property, you can use the built in snippet in visual studio: `propdp`
Simply write "propdp" and that TAB twice. Fill up the fields and it's all good.

Alright so that was easy enough, right? ;)

Now the tougher part: making so-called master pages.
Actually it's not that much different from the background thing.
Declare another dependency property, only this time of type object, or FrameworkElement (better).

Then in your XAML, you declare a kind of placeholder: `ContentControl`. Let's call it MyContentDP for this example:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid Background={"Binding MyBackgroundDP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestoryType=UserControl}}">
     <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding MyContentDP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestoryType=UserControl}}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can then fine tune whatever else you want to provide in this "master view", add a border around the Grid, put some flowers, you name it.

Once you're done, this is how you use it, assuming it was called MyUserControl

```
<Window ...
       xmlns:local="...reference_to_your_usercontrol_dll/exe">
   <Grid>
      <local:MyUserControl MyBackgroundDP="Red">
         <local:MyUserControl.MyContentDP>
            <!-- More XAML declarations here -->
         </local:MyUserControl.MyContentDP>
      </local:MyUserControl>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the performance point:

If you put all the XAML for this as a Custom control (which is **DIFFERENT** from a UserControl), you can then put all the XAML in your App.xaml
Why? because parsing XAML can be an intensive operation, and if you make WP7/SL parse it at runtime whenever you need it, you lose performance.
Instead, your App.xaml gets parsed at startup, then it's in memory. That's what's done in the loading of your application. You would get a performance boost, although it would be minimal for controls made of few XAML, it is still a good practice.

Hope this helps,

Bab.